# Python での正規表現が意図した通りにマッチしない

Tags: python, 正規表現

うまく正規表現が機能しません。

**現在のコード:**

```
pattern1 = 'd+(G|M|k)?$'
repatter = re.compile(pattern)
result = repatter.match(i)
```

**対象の元データ:**

```
12_10G
13_1G
```

**期待するデータ:**

```
10G
1G
```

と出てくるようにしたいのですが、引っかかる文字列がありません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `re.match`は完全一致です。部分一致は[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.search)を使いましょう。
- 正規表現のエスケープシーケンスは`\d`などバックスラッシュが必要です。

**サンプルコード**

```
import re
#pattern = r'\d+(G|M|k)?$'
pattern = r'\d+[GMk]?$'    # こんな書き方もできます。
repattern = re.compile(pattern)
words = ['12_10G', '13_1G', '14_0T']
for word in words:
    result = repattern.search(word)
    if result:
        print(result.group(0))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。お陰様で解決しました。